# JsLint in sublime text 2

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, jslint

How to make jslint don't display logs if it doesn't find any errors in sublime text 2.

Normally, it displays like this

[image: jslint]

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using sublime-jslint and not the other JSlint package...

This is your culprit:

```
if end and not self.use_node_jslint:
    text = '\njslint: ignored ' + str(self.ignored_error_count) + ' errors.\n'
    self.output_view.insert(edit, self.output_view.size(), text)
```

That snippet is from the `jslint.py` located in the `sublime-jslint` folder in your packages directory.  Just go ahead and comment out line 114 and that should suppress the "ignored" message.  To remove the "lint free!" message, comment out line 132.